# Jasmine: expected spy to have been called with [argList1] but actual calls were [argList1], [argList2]

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

In my actual code I have a `forEach` loop, like so:

```
function toTest(myObj) {
    Object.keys(myObj).forEach((key) => {
        doSomething(x, y, [{key, t}]);
    }
}
```

In the test file, I have in `beforeEach`:
`myObj = {prop1, prop2};` and `doSomething = jasmine.createSpy("doSomething");`

and then in `it`: `expect(doSomething).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);`, which passes, but when I try to check the call arguments, `expect(addSSINodeCb).toHaveBeenCalledWith(x, y, [prop1, t])`, jasmine shoots out:

> Expected spy doSomething to have been called with [ x, y, [ Object({
>   prop1, t}) ] ] but actual calls were [ x, y, [ Object({ prop1,
>   t }) ] ], [ x, y, [ Object({ prop2, t }) ] ].

The thing is that the same code works just fine in a similar situation when my function only takes an argument, checking it twice (in any order) is fine.

I also tried checking `expect(doSomething .calls.allArgs()).toEqual([ [x, y, [prop1, t]], [x, y, [prop2, t]] ]);` but I actually get that I'm providing the arguments in the wrong order (i.e. that `prop2` should come before `prop1` which looks wrong to me.

Anyone have any idea? Sorry about obfuscating the code, in my real code the t is actually dependent on the key, but I don't think that matters...

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my issue by using 
`expect(doSomething.calls.argsFor(0)).toEqual([x, y, [prop1, t]]]);` and `expect(doSomething.calls.argsFor(2)).toEqual([x, y, [prop2, t]]]);` though I am still curious as to what exactly was happening above..